# why a projective module is a projective cover for its largest semisimple quotient?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, projective-modules

Why a projective module is a projective cover for its largest semisimple quotient? That is - why the projection on the quotient is an essential morphism in this case?

Comment: This question is not quite on-topic on this site, as explained in the FAQ. The FAQ suggests a few other places where your question will be much more at ease. Good luck!

Comment: You should probably accept your answer: otherwise, this question is going to be bumped automatically on the question lists periodically for ever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: if Q is a submodule of a projective module P which projects surjectively on the largest semisimple quotient of P, then Q projects surjectively on each simple quotient of P, and hence Q lies outside of any maximal submodule of P - contradiction.

Comment: In other words, because the kernel is contained in the radical (because the map is surjective and the quotient has zero radical!) 